# Location woes on HTC

Tags: geolocation

If the NSA tracks me via my HTC phone, they must think I am strange... My location never updated. Ever. I tried removing the cache from News and Weather.  Tried using GPS.  Tried using WiFi.  Nothing seems to work.

Is there a canonical way to re-set the location in Android?

Note: Phone is HTC Sensation XL. I have factory re-set it several time, no change: the first location Weather picks stays as the current one whatever I do.  Applications are any weather apps whatsoever. I installed several and none updated their location correctly.

Comment: Eliminate software issues by reinstalling/factory reseting your device. If this does not work, return the device as hardware fault is very likely.

Comment: What's your phone model ? What "location" are you talking about ? Is is that you can't get your location for any application ? Or is it a specific application ?

Comment: Does Google Maps show the correct location? Does it show the correct approximate location when GPS is turned off?

Comment: @DanHulme: Yes, it does whether I use GPS or not.  Clearly, with GPS it is more accurate. ^_~